# Integrating Vue.js with Django

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Is there any way to use `Django (Python)` as backend and `vue.js` as frontend?

Comment: If, according to your post, "Vue.js has some modules that can help [you] to build [your] web app using Django", then these modules are a way to integrate Vue.js with Django.

Comment: @ForceBru not about the modules but I would like to know, how to integrate both of them?

Comment: If my understanding is right, your are trying to ask:
how to use Vue.js as frontend and Django as backend?

Comment: @XinlinFeng Yes! Let me update the question.

Comment: I fear this may be a case of RTFM -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: You can look this solution which was the kind of same question and it can give you the idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/56058954/3756237

Comment: Of course there is. You can use any frontend framework and any backend framework, they're independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on what @Xinlin Feng said, what I might suggest. is to implement a VueJs app within a Django Jinja Template. There are plenty of resources you can find regarding that like [this](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-an-app-with-vuejs-and-django-part-one).

This can be useful in cases of SPAs, like dashboards, in which subsequent calls and updates can be made as a REST API calls to your Django backend application. The tricky part would be including authentication in the front end app, where the user is already authenticated in a session. This is avoided if the user is asked to sign in after the app is launched.

Answer (score 1):

I actually can have an idea, when I doing my intern last year, I was doing the exact same thing you looking for.
My recommendation is to use Django-REST-framework, and it will provide restful api as urls and returning json object to front end. While at the same time, use vue.js to create front end components, in order to retrieve data back from backend and render, just send http request from frontend to urls Django-REST-framework builds.